Handling io_uring submissions in kernel
I need a fast async channel to transfer data from my kernel module to a userspace app. I tried IO_URING. As far as I am concerned, the way its submissions are handled in the kernel is a black box, hence it cannot be used with a specific kernel module. However, I've found this project: https://github.com/ebecz/io_uring-kernel-example which uses a specific chardev to make sure that the module he created receives the submission. That's the easy part. The hard part is the read_iter handler which is present there. I haven't seen any other examples of custom read_iter handlers anywhere on the Internet. And the one in the link above is obsolete. It was written for like v5.4 kernel. I'm on v6.1 and none of that seems to work anymore.
Has anyone else tried to handle IO_URING submissions manually in the kernel or is it just a waste of time to keep trying?
